# npm start runs out of virtualenv

Tags: python, node.js, linux, npm, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv in which I try to run a start script defined in package.json, but somehow npm changes the source and runs outside of the venv.

If I print `which python` for example in that `npm start` script, I get `/usr/local/bin/python`, so not the python from virtualenv.

Any ideas?

**Edit:**

package.json

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "start": "myscript & watchify -o assets/js/mylibs.js -v -d .",
    },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you post the part of the script that invoke npm? With so little information, we can only blind guess. I d say that npm call for the "normal" (in the PATH) python, instead of your virtualenv.

Comment: I added a sample from package.json. So if I run npm start, it does not recognize myscript. If I just run it without npm start, it works.